# I hate this repetition, but how can I fix it- jquery, bootstrap 4 datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I want to use datepicker on two different fields, but each field has different property and I don't want the code repetition, you'll understand what I want by looking my first and second code snippet.

```
// first code snippet give unexpected result, when user change the first field then the second one do the change on the info block, this means that the change function get fired and affect all field at once
$('#first, #second').datepicker({
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
    autoclose: true
}).on("change", function () {
   $(".first-info").remove();
   $(".second-info").remove();
});
```

My second code and this give out a desired result but how to avoid the repetition on datepicker.

```
//first field
$('#first').datepicker({
     format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
     autoclose: true
 }).on("change", function () {
    $(".first-info").remove();
 });
 //second field
 $('#second').datepicker({
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
    autoclose: true
}).on("change", function () {
   $(".second-info").remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Put a common class on all the datepicker fields, then use a `data` attribute on them to specify the relation to be removed. Something like this:

```html
<input type="text" class="datepicker" data-relation=".first-info" />
<input type="text" class="datepicker" data-relation=".second-info" />
```

```js
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
  format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
  autoclose: true
}).on("change", function() {
  let selector = $(this).data('relation');
  $(selector).remove();
});
```

Note that it may also be possible avoid the need for the `data` attribute if you can instead relate the elements using the DOM structure and jQuery's traversal methods such as `closest()`, `find()`, `next()` etc.

Comment: @marc_s, can you explain why when I change date to something like 01/12/2039 it return 01/01/1970